# My React-Redux project is outputting error when I add an event

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have the following stateless function in my React/Redux project:

```
const ListItem = props => {
    return (
        <li className={props.item.expand ? 'expanded' : ''}>
            <img src={`https://someUrl`+props.item.image}
                 alt="Illustration"
                 //onLoad={props.showImage.bind({}, props.item.id)}
                 className={props.item.showIllustration ? 'show' : ''}/>
            <h3 className="title">{props.item.title}</h3>
            <p className="date">
                {moment(props.item.date, "YYYY-MM-DD").format('DD/MM/YY')}
            </p>

            <h3 className="amount">{props.item.amount}</h3>
            <button onClick={props.showItem.bind({}, props.item.id)}>
                {props.item.show ? 'Close' : 'Info'}
            </button>

            {props.item.show ? <ItemDetails id={props.item.id} /> : ''}
        </li>
    )
}
```

It works well. BUT... when I uncomment the `//onLoad` line, the console outputs the following error:

```
Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.
```

I don't understand why it's asking a unique key, if already set it on the parent component:

```
listItems.map(element => {
    return (
        <ListItem
            key={element.id}
            element={element}
        />
    )
})
```

Besides, the error only is shown where I uncomment the event line. What is causing the error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js/43892905#43892905 this can help you.

Comment: @varit05 I've just read it, but actually I haven't find the answer. The problem only happens when I add the "onLoad" event on the <img>. In fact, when I move that event to other tag, (like <h3> for instance), it renders normally without error at all

Comment: can you please create this issue on codesandbox.io?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `showImage` callback?  Including that code could go a long way in helping the community help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved now. I've found the problem was not in the react component, but in the reducer.

Answer (score 0):

Its required to have the `key` attribute on the top-most element in your rendered items, which is `li` in this case. The reason is because ListItem may be the parent, but its just a syntactic placeholder for the actual html elements in its render method.

Therefore you must change to the following:

```
<li key={props.id} className={props.item.expand ? 'expanded' : ''}>
```

Comment: I've already tried adding the key prop into the <li> item, but it keeps throwing the error. Another strange thing is that the error only throws when I add the "onLoad" prop.